# Mysterious command to send code to Mozilla?

Tags: key-bindings, javascript

I accidentally smashed my hand on the bottom right of my keyboard and got the following prompt in the echo area: (I was in the `analyzeDiscussion()` function in js-mode when this happened)

```
 Send analyzeDiscussion to Mozilla? (y or n)
```

What command could have caused this? I tried `C-h l` to get the last keys pressed, but I had already pressed too many keys and it had gone off the top of the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#'js-eval-defun` is bound to <kbd>C-M-x</kbd> in js-mode. Its docstring is "Update a Mozilla tab using the JavaScript defun at point."

Inside it, it has a block of code:

```
(unless (y-or-n-p (format "Send %s to Mozilla? "
                                      (mapconcat #'identity defun-info ".")))
              (message "") ; question message lingers until next command
              (cl-return-from js-eval-defun))
```

Comment: I've always wondered if this would automatically submit a bugreport to mozilla.